# Mockito: how to stub getter setter

Tags: java, testing, mockito

I am kind of new to Mockito and I was wondering how I could stub a get/set pair.

For example

```
public interface Dummy {
     public String getString();
     public void setString(String string);
}
```

How can I make them behave properly: if somewhere in a test I invoke `setString("something");` I would like `getString()` to return "something". Is that feasable or is there a better way to handle such cases?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to mock `Dummy` and can't just use a regular object implementing it?

Comment: What @milkplusvellocet said. Also, if you really want/need to test a setter, you're doing testing and/or setters wrong.

Comment: @milkplusvellocet actually I am stubbing HttpServletRequest and I want the characterSetEncoding property to work. There are way too many methods to implement to use a regular object. This makes me think, can we mock abstract classes? If so, then that would be a solution for me. I will look into tomorrow, I don't have my workspace with me.

Comment: @PhilippReichart I don't want to test the getter/setter, I just want it to work. Maybe using an abstract class could solve my issue?

Comment: @GuillaumePolet Okay, that's a valid reason :) Maybe [Mockito's capture support](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#15) could help you?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I also wanted the getter to return the result of the recent setter-call.

Having

```
class Dog
{
    private Sound sound;

    public Sound getSound() {
        return sound;
    }
    public void setSound(Sound sound)   {
        this.sound = sound;
    }
}

class Sound
{
    private String syllable;

    Sound(String syllable)  {
        this.syllable = syllable;
    }
}
```

I used the following to connect the setter to the getter:

```
final Dog mockedDog = Mockito.mock(Dog.class, Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
// connect getter and setter
Mockito.when(mockedDog.getSound()).thenCallRealMethod();
Mockito.doCallRealMethod().when(mockedDog).setSound(Mockito.any(Sound.class));
```

Answer (score 8):

I can think of three possible approaches.

1. Don't use `HttpServletRequest` directly in your application; make a wrapper class for it, and have an interface for the wrapper class.  Wherever you currently use `HttpServletRequest` in the application, use the interface instead.  Then in the test, have an alternative implementation of this interface.  Then, you don't need a Mockito mock at all.
2. Have a field in your test class that stores the value that you have set the `String` to.  Make two Mockito `Answer` objects; one that returns the value of this field when `getString` is called, and another that sets the value of this field when `setString` is called.  Make a mock in the usual way, and stub it to use both of these answers.
3. Make an abstract class (which can be a static inner class of your test class) that implements the `HttpServletRequest` interface, but has the field that you want to set, and defines the getter and setter.  Then mock the abstract class, and pass the Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS in as a default answer.  When you call the getter or the setter on the mock, the real method will kick in, which is the behaviour you want.

Hopefully, one of these three alternatives will meet your needs.

Comment: HttpSevletRequest is an interface actually, the only thing is that it has way too many methods to implement to want to do that. For the second option, this is maybe the best approach. I would have preferred to use an abstract class which only defines those two methods. I will post the solution I chose.

Comment: Whoops, sorry, I forgot that was an interface.  I'm not sure about option 1 any more; I'd need to know more about your code to know whether I can get this to work.  Do you want to try option 2?  I'm happy to help if you need it.

Comment: Actually, I think that using an abstract class can work in Mockito. All I would have to do is indicate that I want to invoke the "real methods" for the getter and setter. I found this link which could be interesting: http://marcschwieterman.com/blog/simple-stub-creation-with-mockito-partial-mocks/

Comment: Right, you can mock the abstract class, and use the CALLS_REAL_METHODS default answer.  If I remember correctly, you'll get a runtime exception if any of the abstract methods end up getting called, but that shouldn't be a problem, right?

Comment: I tried it and it works nicely. I have some methods which are not stubbed but are invoked and it does not seem to be a problem. Would you care to update your answer with this solution? Else I will answer my own question but I'd prefer not do that

Comment: If you want me to update my answer to describe mocking abstract classes, you'll need to update your question, to make it clear that mocking an abstract class is OK.  Currently, the question only mentions mocking an interface; so an answer that talks about abstract classes would automatically be wrong.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10265/discussion-between-guillaume-polet-and-david-wallace)

Comment: OK, I've updated the answer to include the solution that we came to here.

Answer (score 5):

I've found that this works fine:

```
doAnswer(answer -> when(dummy.getString()).thenReturn((String) answer.getArguments()[0]))
    .when(dummy).setString(any());
```

I have to use the doAnswer(..).when(..) because the setter is a void method. When the setter is called with an object the getter will be set up to respond with the same object.

Very useful when you've got an interface, but no implementations.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case for HttpServletRequest stubbing I strongly recommend to use Spring-Mock framework:
(http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mock/web/package-summary.html)

It has built-in mocks for web based operations.

Otherwise use the Answer to define your own response for your mocked objects (http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/branches/1.8.5/javadoc/org/mockito/stubbing/Answer.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue but didn't want to go with the accepted answer because doing so would cease the mocking of *all* getters and setters in my bean. All I wanted was to create stubs for a single getter/setter pair, not all. As such, I used the following code.

```
@Mock
private Dummy mockDummy;
private final MutableObject<String> stringWrapper = new MutableObject<>();

public TestClass() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    doAnswer(invocationOnMock -> {
        String injectedString = (String)invocationOnMock.getArguments()[0];
        TestClass.this.stringWrapper.setValue(injectedString);
        return null;
    }).when(this.mockDummy).setString(any());
    when(this.mockDummy.getString()).thenAnswer(
            invocationOnMock -> TestClass.this.stringValue.getValue());
}
```

The first lambda implements the `Answer<Void>` anonymous class' [`answer()` method](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.18.3/org/mockito/stubbing/Answer.html#answer-org.mockito.invocation.InvocationOnMock-). Thus, whenever the setter method is executed by the code under test, this stub of that setter records it into the [`MutableObject`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/mutable/MutableObject.html) helper object. This recorded value that was set can then be returned by the getter implementation.