# Mockito mock setter() and override getter()

Tags: java, android, unit-testing

I am not doing a unitTesting on Android Application.

**TextChoiceAdapter.java:**

```
public class TextChoiceAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    public Context context;
    public int selectedPosition = -1;   //Otherwise Android set zero then choice A will be selected automatically
    public void choiceSelection(View rowView, int position){
        if (selectedPosition == position)
            rowView.setBackgroundColor(0xA0FF8000); // orange
        else
            rowView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }
    public TextChoiceAdapter(Context context,int resources, List<String> textChoiceList) {
        super(context, resources, textChoiceList);
        this.context = context;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
      ...
    }
}
```

**TextChoiceAdapterTest.java:**

```
public class TextChoiceAdapterTest{
    private TextChoiceAdapter textChoiceAdapter;
    private ArrayList<String> textChoiceList;
    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        textChoiceList = new ArrayList<>();
        textChoiceList.add("North");
        textChoiceList.add("East");
        textChoiceList.add("West");
        textChoiceList.add("South");
        Context context = mock(Context.class);
        textChoiceAdapter = new TextChoiceAdapter(context, 1, textChoiceList);
    }
    @Test
        public void testChoiceSelection(){
    //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10217793/mockito-how-to-stub-getter-setter

    textChoiceAdapter.selectedPosition = 1;
    Context context = mock(Context.class);

    //Try my own object class.
    class mockRowView extends View{
        int backgroundColor;
        public mockRowView(Context context){
            super(context);
        }
        public void setBAckgroundColor(int a){
            this.backgroundColor = a;
        }
        public int getBackgroundColor(){
            return this.backgroundColor;
        }
    }
    View rowView = mock(mockRowView.class);
    textChoiceAdapter.choiceSelection(rowView, 1);
    assertEquals(rowView.getBackgroundColor(), 0xA0FF8000);
}
}
```

**Error:**
`java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :null
Actual   :-1593868288`

**My question:**
How to `mock` my `rowView` with `setter()` and `getter()` properly?
I want different answer from different input.

I am imitating [Mockito: how to stub getter setter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10217793/mockito-how-to-stub-getter-setter)

Comment: `View rowView = new mockRowView();` ?

Comment: I don't understand why this test needs to use the getter at all. Is `View rowView = mock(View.class); textChoiceAdapter.choiceSelection(rowView, 1); verify(rowView).setBackgroundColor(0xA0FF8000);` not what you need? If not, can you clarify why not?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your attentions Ferrybig and Boris van Katwijk. I will follow your advice from now on.
1. Create `MockRowView` class
2. Mock that class.
3. For `setter` method use. `doCallRealMethod()`
4. Use direct access to variable. Since second time it called will return 0.

```
@Test
    public void testChoiceSelection(){

        textChoiceAdapter.selectedPosition = 1;
        Context context = mock(Context.class);

        //Try my own object class.
        class MockRowView extends View{
            int backgroundColor;
            public MockRowView(Context context){
                super(context);
            }
            @Override
            public void setBackgroundColor(int a){
                this.backgroundColor = a;
            }
            //User direct access will not cause a problem when do assertEquals()
        }

        MockRowView rowView = mock(MockRowView.class);
        doCallRealMethod().when(rowView).setBackgroundColor(anyInt());

        textChoiceAdapter.selectedPosition = 2;
        textChoiceAdapter.choiceSelection(rowView, 1);
        assertEquals(rowView.backgroundColor, Color.TRANSPARENT);
        textChoiceAdapter.choiceSelection(rowView, 2);
        assertEquals(rowView.backgroundColor, 0xA0FF8000);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A small but important note is that the arguments in your `assertEquals` are swapped. The first argument should be what you expect, the second what you actually got.

The error message therefore actually indicated that you have successfully mocked your `rowView` object. When you invoked `getBackgroundColor()`, you got `null`, which is what a mocked object does.

You can specify behaviour for a method on a mocked object using Mockito's `when` mechanism:

```
Mockito.when(rowView.getBackgroundColor()).thenReturn(42);
```

However, I feel like you are actually depending on the natural functionality of the rowView object. You might want to not mock this object, but rather use a naturally created instance. You could mock dependencies of this object if needed. It does not make much sense to call a method of a mocked object in a test assertion.